# make a class with ajax

Tags: javascript, css, dom

How do i make a class with ajax? i have this code

```
function parseResponse(request){
if (request.readyState == 4){
    if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 304){
        var data = request.responseXML;

        var header1Name = data.getElementsByTagName('header1') [0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var text1Name = data.getElementsByTagName('text1') [0].firstChild.nodeValue;

        var header1Elem = document.createElement("h3"); 
        var header1Text = document.createTextNode(header1Name);
        header1Elem.appendChild(header1Text);

        var text1Elem = document.createElement("p");
        var text1Text = document.createTextNode(text1Name);
        text1Elem.appendChild(text1Text);

        var existContent = document.getElementById("information");
        while ( existContent.hasChildNodes() ){
            existContent.removeChild(existContent.lastChild);
        }
        existContent.appendChild(header1Elem);
        existContent.appendChild(text1Elem);
    }
}
```

}

But i have absolutely no idea how to do a class, i want to append the class to the h3 element, any help is much appreciated,by class i mean something like `<h3 class="class">`

Comment: What's a class? Do you mean adding a CSS class-name? Please try to clarify

Comment: i adjusted my question, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: The actual problem has nothing to do with ajax, but is a case of plain DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) property to set the class.

```
header1Elem.className = 'theclass';
```

Or [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Element.setAttribute)

```
header1Elem.setAttribute('class', 'theclass');
```